# R: Write to CSV and continue through piping

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there any way to include a call to write.csv within a string of piped dplyr functions?

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl == 4) %>% 
  write.csv(file = "firstStage.csv") %>% 
  group_by(carb) %>% 
  summarise(hp.sum = sum(hp)) %>%
  write.csv(file = "secondStage.csv")
```

I could create my own function:

```
csv2go <- function(x, ...) {
  write.csv(x, ...)
  x
}
```

but was wondering if there is a something that does this in base or dplyr. Maybe the `write_csv()` function in `library(readr)` could adopt this option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very simple!!!  All you need to do is to add a single character "T" to convert the regular pipe operator %>% to the Tee-pipe operator %T>% like this:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
   filter(cyl == 4) %T>%                  # <== Tee-pipe operator 
   write.csv(file = "firstStage.csv") %>% 
   group_by(carb) %>% 
   summarise(hp.sum = sum(hp)) %>%
   write.csv(file = "secondStage.csv")
```

%T>% is your new friend

Comment: Hi Luke, if this is the correct answer can your mark it (I need the points). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you need ? This is how I write csvs onto HDFS.

```
write.csv(data, file=pipe("hadoop dfs -put - /tmp/test.csv"))
```